# Java Get an exception while calling a web service but the Exception is empty

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j

I am calling a web service using the following code

```
public static ServResponse enGenderAndSentiment(String url, Tweet t) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String responseBody = "";
        ServResponse holder = null;

        try {
            # calling a web service here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.debug("Exception while calling api for : " + t.getId());
            logger.debug(ex);
        } finally {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }       

        return holder;

    }
```

An exception is thrown while executing the previous code and when I check the log file, I found the message Exception while calling ... but I the exception itself is not logged.

What could be the problem here? why the second logging statement is not printing anything in the log file?

Comment: Can you show us the log?

Comment: Could be happening because of your logger, is the current level > debug? try to simply printStackTrace and see what you got.

Comment: @MehdiB. Huh? On a server? What makes you think that printing a stack trace to the console would be visible anywhere?

Comment: @GhostCat, Websphere does print the stack trace on the sys err log file.

Comment: @MehdiB. but that assumes he is using websphere ...

Comment: It could be that logging is misconfigured: check the config file.

Comment: @GhostCat - Also a typical Tomcat installation captures stdout/stderr in a log file.  AFAIK, it not unusual behavior for a web container ... because lots of people write crappy webapp software that does that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `logger.error(ex,ex);` instead of `logger.debug(ex);` to log also the stacktrace (with optional cause exceptions)...